# Check if a timezone is valid in R

Tags: r

I am reading a file that contains timestamps and a timezone specification. I would like to be able to detect if a given timezone on this file is recognized by R or not, and supply my own default in case it isn't.

However, it seems like as.POSIXct silently falls back to UTC if given an invalid timezone, with no error or warning I could catch and handle:

```
> as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz="blah")
[1] "1970-01-01 UTC"
```

What would be a 'proper' way in R to check if a given timezone is recognized or not?

Comment: As `?as.POSIXct` says, see `?"time zones"`

Comment: ... in particular `example('time zones')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`help("time zones")` explains a lot of the issues with time zones in detail and is well worth the read.

Results will vary based on your OS, but `example("time zones")` shows how you can read a zone.tab file if your OS has one.

```
tzfile <- "/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab"
tzones <- read.delim(tzfile, row.names = NULL, header = FALSE,
                     col.names = c("country", "coords", "name", "comments"),
                     as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE, comment.char = "#")
str(tzones$name)
#chr [1:415] "Europe/Andorra" "Asia/Dubai" "Asia/Kabul" "America/Antigua" "America/Anguilla" ...

NROW(tzones)
#[1] 415

head(tzones)
#  country      coords             name comments
#1      AD +4230+00131   Europe/Andorra         
#2      AE +2518+05518       Asia/Dubai         
#3      AF +3431+06912       Asia/Kabul         
#4      AG +1703-06148  America/Antigua         
#5      AI +1812-06304 America/Anguilla         
#6      AL +4120+01950    Europe/Tirane
```

Comment: Windows users can find zone.tab at R_HOME/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab

Answer (score 4):

You could use a timezone library which has knowledge of time zones.  This is from the SVN version of RcppBDT:

```
R> tz <- new(bdtTz, "America/Chicago")     
R> cat("tz object initialized as:       ", format(tz), "\n")    
tz object initialized as:        America/Chicago   
R>     tzBAD <- new(bdtTz, "blah")     
Error in new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :    
  Unknown region supplied, no tz object created       
R>
```

In general, time zone support is dependent on the operating system. So for a portable solution you need to supply a list of valid time zones from somewhere...

And for what it is worth, I am using the csv file from the Boost sources.  A copy of that time zones file is eg [here at github](https://github.com/boost-vault/date_time/blob/master/date_time_zonespec.csv).

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled on this question since I was looking to figure out the same thing. Turned out using the following. Leaving this for anyone who might stumble on this question...

```
is.valid.timezone <- function(timezone) {
  return(timezone %in% (OlsonNames()))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denis! I think this is the best answer for most users, as it can be done in baseR without external libraries or calls to OS resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Rmetrics` package `timeDate` package to check for timezone.

```
require(timeDate)

timeDate("1970-01-01", zone = "Africa/Dakar")
## [1] [1970-01-01]

timeDate("1970-01-01", zone = "blah")
## Error in .formatFinCenterNum(unclass(ct), zone, type = "any2gmt") : 
##  'blah' is not a valid FinCenter.
```

Comment: I think that just uses `timeDate::listFinCenter()` which may not be up-to-date since it's just a vector stored in the package.

Comment: May be but we don't have any evidence that is not updated. Therefore, why an ASCII file in Unix system with timezone will be more reliable.

Comment: a) Because the distro may update it. b) Answer valid only of subset of machines running such setup, leaving out other Linux systems, Windows, OS X, ...  In sum, this is why R ships its copy of Olson's db in its sources too...

Comment: @dickoa Currently `listFinCenter()` has 397 timezones and `example('time zones')` has 415 (at least on my disto)

Comment: @GSee care to add the example as an answer?

Comment: @GSee I see you are right. I checked and in my distro (Arch) I have 418. Thanks