# How to convert datetime values to right timezone?

Tags: r

I have datetime values like

```
val <- c(1376517610, 1376519412, 1376528711, 1376528411, 1376528411)
```

I wan't to convert these values to datetime and I'm trying this using

```
> as.POSIXct(val, tz="EEST", origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
[1] "2013-08-14 22:00:10 GMT" "2013-08-14 22:30:12 GMT" "2013-08-15 01:05:11 GMT"
[4] "2013-08-15 01:00:11 GMT" "2013-08-15 01:00:11 GMT"
Warning messages:
1: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'EEST'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'EEST'
3: In strptime(x, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'EEST'
4: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
  unknown timezone 'EEST'
5: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'EEST'
```

But my timezone is EEST

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "EEST"
```

How to solve this problem and convert this data into the right timezone?

Comment: Have you tried using a full Olson time zone ID, e.g. "America/New_York"?

Comment: Related to [Check if a timezone is valid in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17345516/271616)

Comment: Your code works without problem on my system. Could it be a system specific issue? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use my timezone using that format (Europe/Helsinki) but it is still 2 hours less than it should be.

Comment: I can't replicate a 2 hour difference on Win7 Enterprise. Using my current local time in Australia and transferring to Helsinki via: `as.POSIXct(as.numeric(Sys.time()), tz="Europe/Helsinki", origin = '1970-01-01')` matches the time for Helsinki reported by Google.

Answer (score 1):

As was the case for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501097/something-wrong-in-convert-iso-8601-date-times-with-a-posixct-object), you shouldn't specify the daylight saving time timezone, just use the normal timezone, the system will understand it is summer time because of the date:

```
as.POSIXct(val, tz="EET", origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
[1] "2013-08-14 23:00:10 EEST" "2013-08-14 23:30:12 EEST" "2013-08-15 02:05:11 EEST" "2013-08-15 02:00:11 EEST" "2013-08-15 02:00:11 EEST"
```

NB: I posted this answer because I think it resolves the "unknown timezone" issue. However there is indeed still the issue that it appears as UTC +1 when it should be UTC +3. Using "Europe/Helsinki" gives the same error (at least for me on Mac OS X 10.6 and R 2.14.2, with french locale):

```
as.POSIXct(val, tz="Europe/Helsinki", origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
[1] "2013-08-14 23:00:10 EEST" "2013-08-14 23:30:12 EEST" "2013-08-15 02:05:11 EEST" "2013-08-15 02:00:11 EEST" "2013-08-15 02:00:11 EEST"
```